# How to SVN Checkout for a created SVN?

Tags: svn, amazon-ec2, tortoisesvn

I created a SVN in Amazon  EC2 server. it is at /data/svn/repos/

And i do my development work in windows. And I have 3 different projects. One part is in PHP, one is plane HTML/JS and other part is JSP. So i need to commit those three into 3 different subfolders in my SVN.

And if it is possible i like them to auto deploy into PHP and HTML/JS into Apache and JSP into Tomcat.

I dont know how to get the url to checkOut. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to connect to your repository. If you have tortoise SVN installed, then:

- Create a new folder on your PC where you want to store your repository contents
- Right-click the folder and select SVN Checkout…
- Enter the URL to your repository and select OK
- Enter your username and password

Thus you will get empty folder where you can add files/folders and commit them to the repository.

It is standard to have trunk/branches/tags layout, thus I'd recommend stick to that, thus
you should create the following structure in this folder:

```
 /php/trunk
     /branches
     /tags
 /html/trunk
     /branches
     /tags
 /jsp/trunk
     /branches
     /tags
```

[Here](http://codetunnel.com/blog/post/91/tortoisesvn-basics-tutorial) you can find step-by-step further instructions.